# In a visual studio extension identifying if the solution is opened in release or debug

Tags: c#, configuration, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to create a VS extension that will automate some of the repetitive work done by hand when building a new version of a project (like moving .MSI files around and stuff like that). I wish for the extension to different things based on the solution configuration debug/release status.

In simple terms - If the user is working on a solution in debug configuration and than presses my extension button it will do something different than if he is working on a release configuration. The question is, how can I while in the extension context identify the working configuration of the solution?

any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Bear in mind - developers can create *more* configurations than the *default* two that most project templates come with, and they can mix and match project configuration options in the solution configuration. Are you sure you want to base this off of configuration rather than specific project/solution properties (such as output directories)?

Comment: Wow, great comment. I defiantly didn't consider that scenario, thank you for that remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`SolutionConfiguration2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/envdte80.solutionconfiguration2.aspx):

```
DTE dte = (DTE)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
SolutionBuild builder = dte.Application.Solution.SolutionBuild;
SolutionConfiguration2 config = (SolutionConfiguration2)builder.ActiveConfiguration;
```

The MSDN page also contains an example how to read the needed properties

Comment: Thanks Stephan that looks promising, however, I can't seem to get the dte object, consider a command button on the tools menu and a callback function that is supposed to be run when its pressed, how will the function get the proper dte object?

Comment: `DTE dte = (DTE)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)); `

Comment: Oh got it, I marked your answer as accepted and I suggest you edit it with the last comment you added to make it complete.